# Dell monitor changes brightness automatically between applications, how can I disable this?

Tags: windows-7, display, brightness

I have a Dell monitor that changes brightness when I task from application to application. I think the culprit is the program Dell Display Manager. Let me observe this a little longer. The question is how can I disable the automatic changing of brightness between applications.

Comment: Is it connected to a laptop based on Intel CPU?

Comment: Usually the monitor settings (in the monitor OSD) will have an "eco" mode or other power saving feature. Alternatively it might have a "gaming" or other display mode that adjusts this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Brightness is enabled in Windows 7.

To disable Adaptive Brightness, either run Services.msc or go to Control Panel-> Administrative Tools -> Services and set Adaptive Brightness to manual or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have [Dynamic Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_ratio#Dynamic_contrast_(DC)) (automatically adjusts picture based on content on screen) enabled in your display settings. This means that you're not using the "Standard" color preset (setting not available in all presets), e.g. "Gaming", "Movie".

To stop this behavior, you can either:

1. Change your preset to one that doesn't use Dynamic Contrast (e.g. "Standard")
2. Turn off "Dynamic Contrast" in your display settings